# Getting the number of values in a char buffer (from file read) in C

Tags: c

I would like to read characters from a file on a single line (for a school exercise). The exercise statest that the string is a maximum of 1000 characters.

Using the following code I was able to read the file content in a char[]:

```
FILE *fp;
const int buffsize = 1000;
char *filepath = argv[1];
char buff[buffsize];

fp = fopen(filepath, "r");
fscanf(fp, "%s", buff);
//buff has the file contents
```

Considering these includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

This seem to work fine however when I want to iterate over the array it goes way beyond the actual array length (because i fixed the buffsize at 1000 I assume). How could I approach this in a better way, so I can iterate over the correct number of indices?

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the length of a string?

Comment: Well, I tried to do this using: sizeof(buff) / sizeof(char) 
but this does not seem to give the correct number. I thought maybe I forget something

Comment: As above, the easiest way is to use `fgets` instead of `fscanf`, since it returns the number of chars read (= the length of the string)

Comment: Since `fscanf()` doesn't care about newlines, and `%s` stops at the first white space (which includes blanks, tabs and newlines), when you need line-based input, you shouldn't use the `scanf()` family of functions to read the input (but you can use `sscanf()` to parse a line read by another mechanism).  Use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX's
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read a line and go from there.

Comment: Please, post a complete example, not snippets (which probably extend even more than your whole program) and the full output of it, read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the length (which is a better term since it has little to do with the size of the buffer it's in) of a string, use `strlen()`:

```
const size_t len = strlen(buff);
```

This will count the number of characters before the first 0-character, which is how strings are terminated ("end-marked") in C.

Now you can iterate using an index if you want:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  printf("The character at index %zu is '%c'\n", i, buff[i]);
```

Note that many C programmers would iterate over the buffer directly instead, using a pointer:

```
for(const char *s = buff; *s != '\0'; ++s)
  printf("Found character '%c'\n", *s);
```

Answer (score 0):

A C-"string" of 1000 characters requires a buffer of 1000+1=1001 `char`s, as a C-"string"'s end is indicated by an additional `0`.

So to enable your code to actually read 1000 characters, change

```
const int buffsize = 1000;
```

to be

```
const int buffsize = 1000 + 1;
```

and to make sure to also just scan in 1000 `char`s and not overflow `buff`, change

```
fscanf(fp, "%s", buff);
```

to be

```
fscanf(fp, "%1000s", buff);
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about the 1000 + 1 part (I am used to python). However, if the string to be read is smaller than 1000, let's say 800 characters, then it would still create an array of 1001 characters is that Correct?

If i want to loop over that array i only need the first 800 characters. I am still not sure how to get the "actual" size then.

Comment: The buffer as per `buffsize` size is created already with this statement: `char buff[buffsize];`

Comment: After a successful (hint, hint ;-) call to `scanf()` you can determine the number of `char`s actually read by calling `strlen(buffer)`.